# What is the rule-of-thumb relation between sample size and feature vector dimension?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

It is generally known that larger the no. of features making a up a feature vector, the more number of samples are needed to train a classifier. In my case, I'm using a backpropagation multi-layer perceptron in a two-class problem with around 256 features making up a feature vector.

Now my sample size is not infinite. About 2000 positive and 2000 negative samples.

Before working out some dimension-reduction procedures and all of that, I'd like to find out if there's any such relation between no. of samples and no. of dimensions in feature vector.

Answer (score 2):

There is no actual direct relationship between the two, as the necessary amount of training data depends also on the complexity of the model and the training procedure used.

From the practical point of view, I would suggest running a simple discriminative classifier first to see how it works with all the features and then probably applying some sort of feature selection.

Comment: soufanom, this isn't about solving systems of equations, really. Moreover, it is sometimes possible to find a good classifier even if the number of features significantly exceeds the number of training samples.